# create_image() function python only displays last image in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create a program that shows a series of images in a loop, but the create_image() function only draws the last image I try to draw.

```
for i in range(len(imgList)): 
    filename = PhotoImage(file = str(imgList[i]).lower() + ".png")
    C.create_image(45 * (i + 1), 5, anchor=NE, image=filename)
    print("created image")
```

This prints "created image" however many times it needs to, but only the last image is shown.
imgList is just the name of all the images

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

When displaying images in tkinter, you need to keep references to variables they were assigned to otherwise they get garbage collected. Try the following:

```
c.images = list()
for i in range(len(imgList)): 
    image = PhotoImage(file = str(imgList[i]).lower() + ".png")
    c.create_image(45 * (i + 1), 5, anchor=NE, image=image)
    c.images.append(image)
    print("created image")
```